# Only 14 Delete Votes but it Says I Have 30

Tags: support, vote-to-delete

It's only 2.75 hours into the new day, and I'm already out of delete votes. That's not impossible (I am a proud deleter), but seemed unlikely. The "Votes/Delete" tab in my profile suggests that I'm right:

[image]

What happened to my missing 16 delete votes?

Comment: My guess is that you cast 30 delete votes. And then 16 of those posts got deleted and no longer show up in your list.

Comment: Wow. I guess I'm a "delete fiend" if I got 30 in just the last hour or so - I only just got home about 7pm-Arizona time. That's only one hour to cast 30 delete votes.